# Getting null value of the height of the div in a vue component when hosted on the net

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vue-component

I have a div that contains the chat messages. Here is the code i did:

```
<template>
 <div class="panel-block">
        <div class="chat" v-if="chats.length != 0"  id="myDiv">
         <div v-for="chat in chats" style="overflow: hidden;" >
             <div class="chat-right" v-if="chat.user_id == userid">
                 {{ chat.chat }}
             </div>
             <div class="chat-left" v-else>
                 {{ chat.chat}}
             </div>
         </div>

        </div>
        <div v-else class="no-message">
            <br><br><br><br><br>
            There are no messages
        </div>
        <chat-composer v-bind:userid="userid" v-bind:chats="chats" v-bind:adminid="adminid"></chat-composer>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['chats','userid','adminid'],

    created: function () {
        $(window).load(function() {
            $("#myDiv").scrollTop($("#myDiv")[0].scrollHeight)
        });
      }

    }

</script>
```

I want the div to automatically scroll down to the bottom of the div once the page is loaded. I have no problem running it on my local machine. The code works perfectly but when i hosted my application, sometimes it does not work and it gives me this error on the console of the browser - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined`. It is so weird because sometimes it works and sometimes it does not. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if `chats.length` is zero, the myDiv would not be rendered to the page, right?  That seems like an issue for `$("#myDiv")[0].scrollHeight`

Comment: its malfunctioning even thought my chats.length is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the instance is mounted when the callback to scroll the browser window is executed.

You should scroll the browser window on guarantee that the instance is mounted and all its children. This provides certainty that by the time jquery selection for #myDiv is made, the template has rendered to the browser. *e.g.*

```
...

mounted: function () {
    const scrollDiv = function () {
        const myDiv = $(this.$el).find("#myDiv");
        myDiv.scrollTop(myDiv[0].scrollHeight);
    }
    this.$nextTick(scrollDiv);
}
```

Comment: when i tried your code on my local machine, i am getting this error -  `Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined"`

Comment: Seems just as much as what @Taplar wrote in his comment. If chats.length is 0, `div#myDiv` isn't rendered. Also I updated my code to always make selection in the rendered component.